# Trying to draw two digits and equal distance from the centre

Tags: java, java-2d, drawing2d

I want it to look symmetrical, but I can't work out why this doesn't work.

```
Font scoreFont = new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 72);
    g.setFont(scoreFont);
    FontMetrics scoreFontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.drawString("" + playerOneScore, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
            - 30 - scoreFontMetrics.charWidth(playerOneScore),
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
    g.drawString("" + playerTwoScore,
            SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 + 30,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);

}
```

### Thanks in advance.

Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `charWidth` in `FontMetrics` gets a `char` as a parameter. If `playerOneScore` is an `int` than it is actually transformed to its `char` value and then that is applied to the method. You would be better using `stringWidth(playerOneScore + "");`